# multi query for search mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to write advance query to search in mongoose use nodejs,

code at search.js (nodejs)

```
let queryOptions = {};

if(req.body.title){
    queryOptions.title = {$regex:key ,$options:"i"};
}   
if(req.body.name){
    queryOptions.name = {$regex:key ,$options:"i"};
}
if(req.body.tags){
    queryOptions.tags = {$regex:key ,$options:"i"};
}

Room.find({$or: [queryOptions]}, (err,rooms)=>{})
```

the form data Like this

```
key:"hello"
name:false
tags:false
title:true
```

mongoose return empty result when checked two property like this

```
key:"hello"
name:true
tags:false
title:true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because your query is wrong

Use this one

```
let queryOptions = [];

if(req.body.title){
    queryOptions.push({title: {$regex:key ,$options:"i"}})
}   
// ...

Room.find({$or: queryOptions}, (err,rooms)=>{})
```

Comment: can I ask another question if tags is a another schema and i want search in it also and get rooms with relation !

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo please explain what you want. Can you send schemas?
Also please mark as right answer if it works :)

Comment: the room schema is linking with another schema called tags ` tags :[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Tag'
    }]` i want search about room by tags , like looking for rooms these link with sport tag

Comment: I think the best way is to do two querys. First you need to find all tag ID-s, 
and then push them to your queryOptions as regex